# What is the best algorithm for finding related post?

Tags: database-design

Basically this is a database and query question. How do you implement related post in your site, suppose you have this table:

```
+------+        +------+
+ Post +        + Tags  +
-------- N : M  --------
```

where post have the body and link m:n to tag. This is a very common scenario of implement tag and post.

so, How do you implement related post in your site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find all the posts which overlap on at least one tag and use [term frequency - inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to weight the tags by importance, and sum the weights. Return related posts in descending order of total weight.